# JBDC and MYSQL Null values inserting into table

Tags: mysql, jdbc, exception

Below is simple Login system. At the moment it will allow me to enter a blank username and password, into the table even though each index is specified as being NOT NULL? It wont allow me to enter duplicates which is what I wanted but how do I catch blank parameters from being entered? What am I missing?

Registration Servlet

```
....
LoginService loginService = new LoginService();
            connection = loginService.getConnection(connection);
            loginService.addNewUser(preparedStatement, connection, newUserId, newUserPassword, newUserFirstName, newUserLastName);
...
```

LoginService method addNewUser

```
public void addNewUser(PreparedStatement ps, Connection connection, String newUserId, String newUserPassword,String newUserFirstName,String newUserLastname) throws SQLException
    {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (userId ,password , userFirstName, userLastName)VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, newUserId);
        ps.setString(2, newUserPassword);
        ps.setString(3, newUserFirstName);
        ps.setString(4, newUserLastname);

        ps.executeUpdate();

    }
```

Comment: Is it blank or actually `NULL`?

Comment: sorry it is blank, Is that not considered the same thing?

Comment: No it isn't, some database do consider blank to be equivalent to NULL (eg Oracle), but the SQL standard and most databases considers blank distinct from any other value (including blanks). See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: I didn't realize. Thank you

Comment: Just noticed I typo in my previous comment, I meant to say "considers NULL distinct from any other value (including blanks)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around of your current issue, you can add this to the beginning of addNewUser method (before the line: ps = connection.prepareStatement("...");)

```
if (newUserId != null && "".equals(newUserId.trim()))
    newUserId = null;
if (newUserPassword != null && "".equals(newUserPassword.trim()))
    newUserPassword = null;
```

You should pass real NULL value in the JDBC parameters (empty strings are not good enough)